# ASP.NET MVC 5 - Strange behaviour having HTML content in model

Tags: c#, html, .net, asp.net-mvc, exception

I am working on a functionality based on ASP.NET MVC 5 to manage message templates which are rendered as html. Having html-markup in the viewmodel causes some problems.

Those message templates are edited via a WYSIWYG-editor.

### Here a basic example of the **controller**:

```
public class BlackboardController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Template()
    {
        return View(new RichTextEditorViewModel()
        {
            Message = "<h1>I'm a headline</h1><p>I'm a regular text...</p>"
        });
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Template(RichTextEditorViewModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return View(model);

        return RedirectToAction("Template");
    }
}
```

### Basic example of the **model**:

```
public class RichTextEditorViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Template name")]
    public string TemplateName { get; set; }

    [AllowHtml]
    [Display(Name = "Message")]
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

### Part of the view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Template", "Blackboard", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Message </label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="input-group">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Message, new { rows = "20", style = "resize:none;width:400px;", placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Message), @class = "form-control input-lg textarea-editor" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Save template" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

---

Everything works fine when I post a html-markup to the controller action. To make that work, I had to decorate the model property containing the markup with the AllowHtml-attribute.

**BUT:** If the ModelState is not valid, e.g. TemplateName is null, then I still get that `HttpRequestValidationException` saying:

> "A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the
>   client"

I couldn't reproduce that behaviour with that basic example, but it happens in my more complex web application. On some sites I found the information, that an exception gets thrown if anything touches a property of the Request-property of the controller or view. Tried to work on that, but it didn't seem to help. Also, I don't know what components are actually accessing the request or containing a reference to that request.

How can it be, that I won't see this exception if the ModelState is valid. And how can it be, that the `HttpRequestValidationException` gets thrown when the ModelState is invalid.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client)

Comment: @KennethK. not a duplicate sind I am using the AllowHtml-attribute and still get a strange behaviour.

Comment: If you remove the [Required] from TemplateName, does it give you the same error?

Comment: @BrianP no I don't get the same error. Somehow it seems to work then. But this property needs to be marked as required.

Comment: @Tom I am betting that it has to do with route selection.  It is looking for a route that does not require the TemplateName.  If this is the only place you use the ViewModel, I would remove the required attribute and then manually handle that validation.  Also would be good practice to make sure the client side is enforcing it.

Comment: @BrianP I just tried that. I get the same error when having an error in the ModelState.
`if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.TemplateName))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(nameof(model.TemplateName), "The template-name is required.");
                return View(model);
            }`